# average and variance based on keys in a dataset

Tags: dataset, average, variance, tableau-api

I have a dataset (txt) like:

```
user1    place1    4.0
user1    place2    1.0
user1    place3    3.0
user2    place2    2.0
user3    place1    3.0
user3    place3    4.0
```

The columns are the user IDs, the place IDs and the scores (0.0~5.0).

I want to analyze and visualize this dataset with tableau.
First, I'd like to calculate the average and variance of the scores of each place and each user.

Is there an easy way to do this?
In my current impression, maybe I have to divide this dataset to multiple tables (user table, place table and user-place-score table)...

I'm a completely new user of tableau, so I'm happy if anyone would give me a hint to start with tableau.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One feature to experiment with is the Summary card in Tableau. It will display various descriptive statistics for the current selection.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is very easy with tableau.

[This official video from tableau around 6:30](http://www.tableausoftware.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/analyzing-0) shows how to visualize average scores of each user and each site. [It](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#datafields_fieldproperties_aggregation.html) shows how to use other aggregation measures.